# How to declare global variable inside function?

Tags: c++, variables, loops, global, program-entry-point

I have problem creating global variable inside function, this is simple example:

```
int main{
   int global_variable;  //how to make that
}
```

This is exactly what I want to do:

```
int global_variable;
int main{
                   // but I wish to initialize global variable in main function
}
```

Comment: Loop? I think you mean *function*. These are veeeery different things.

Comment: you can still do int global_variable outside of main, then set global_variable = something; inside main.

Comment: I think that you are trying to utilize different languages behaviors and styles in C++. I would suggest a quick walk through Bjarne Stroustrup book "C++".

Comment: As soon as you declare your variable inside a function it is considered local, by definition. This makes no sense.

Comment: @cen Don't you mean "As soon as you _declare_"  It is perfectly fine to initialize the global in the function.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `main` is not a loop. It's a function.
2. Your function syntax is wrong. You need to have parentheses after the function name. Either of these are valid syntaxes for `main`:

   ```
    int main() {
    }

    int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    }
   ```

Then, you can declare a local variable inside `main` like so:

```
int main() {
  int local_variable = 0;
}
```

or assign to a global variable like so:

```
int global_variable;

int main() {
  global_variable = 0;
}
```

Comment: But can I initialize global variable inside main?

Comment: @user3137147 No. A global variable is by definition declared (and perhaps initialised) in the global namespace.

Comment: @sftrabbit Perhaps I am getting mixed up, but isn't your last example initializing your `global_variable` inside main? Or is that not considered initialization?

Comment: @Jordan Initialisation is when you give an object a value as soon as it is brought into existence. If the `= 0;` had been in the variable declaration, it would have been initialisation. There are other ways to initialise variables too (constructor initialization list, function arguments, etc.).

Comment: @Jordan `global_variable` *is* being initialized with the value 0 in that example, but not because of the assignment. Objects with static storage duration (like `global_variable`) are automatically zero-initialised. So really, the line in `main` is unnecessary.

Comment: @sftrabbit I see, I always though that initialization is just when you first give a variable a value, not that it _has_ to happen right when you declare it.

Answer (score 12):

There is no way to *declare* it the way you want. And that's it.

But:

- First, if you want you can declare it before the `main` body but assign a value  to it inside `main`. Look Paul's answer for that
- Second, actually there is no advantage of declaring variables the way you want. They are *global* and that means they should be declared in the *global* scope and no other places.

Answer (score 6):

```
int global_variable;
int main()
{
               global_variable=3; // look you assigned your value.
}
```

Comment: -1. For not having the parentheses and calling an assignment initialisation.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Oops, fixed. After 3 years haha.

Answer (score 1):

well... 
its indirectly possible by declaring pointers global, and later assigning local variables to them, but sometimes it may lead to situations where pointed variable is unaccessible .

Comment: just put memory adress of the object to the pointers in short ;' void *x,*y,*z; int main(){ char localx[500]="hello eorld from local area"; x=&localx; }' ; probably will do the task simuleneusly;